# Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with Swagger and Foreman Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

I have my server currently running at 0.0.0.0:5100. When I try to access my Swagger docs, I get the following error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0/api/v1/types.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:5100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am wondering why is that happening. Here is my Swagger configuration in index.html:

```
$(function () {
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
      url: "/api-docs.json",
      dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
      supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
      onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
        log("Loaded SwaggerUI");

        if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
          /*
          initOAuth({
            clientId: "your-client-id",
            realm: "your-realms",
            appName: "your-app-name"
          });
          */
        }
        $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
          hljs.highlightBlock(e)
        });
      },
      onFailure: function(data) {
        log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
      },
      docExpansion: "none"
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you enabled [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) support for your web-service?  [The Swagger documentation](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/CORS) calls out that CORS support is required for that to work.  The error message you are getting is the exact same message I was getting on my Grails project before I added CORS support.

Answer (score -4):

**Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *** extension on chrome store added into the browser.

Note: Once you done with work disable this options becasue youtube will not work with enable option.